# How to effectively use spark to read cassandra data that has partition hotspots?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

From everything I can tell, spark uses at most one task per cassandra partition when reading from cassandra.  Unfortunately, I have a few partitions in cassandra that are enormously unbalanced (bad initial table design).  I need to read that data into a new table, which will be better designed to handle the hotspots, but any attempt to do so with normal spark avenues won't work effectively; I'm left with a few tasks (10+) running forever, working on those few enormous partition keys.

To give you an idea of scale, this is working on a table that is about 1.5TB in size, spread over 5 servers with a replication factor of 3; ~ 500GB per node.

Other ideas are welcome, though just dumping to CSV is probably not a realistic option.

Materialized view creation is also a no-go, so far; it takes entirely too long, and at least on 3.0.8, there is little to no monitoring during the creation.

Answer (score 3):

This is a difficult problem which can't really be solved automatically *but* if you know how your data is distributed within your really huge files I can give you an option.

Instead of doing a single RDD/DataFrame to represent your table, split it into multiple calls which are unioned.

Basically you want to do this

Given our biggest partition is set up like this

```
Key1 -> C1, C2, C3, ..., C5000000
```

And we know in general C is distributed like

```
Min C = 0
Max C = 5000000
Average C = 250000
```

We can guess that we can cut up these large partitions pretty nicely by doing range pushdowns every 100K C values.

```
val interval = 100000
val maxValue = 500000
sc.union(
 (0 until maxValue by interval).map{ lowerBound => 
   sc.cassandraTable("ks", "tab")
     .where(s"c > $lowerBound AND c < ${lowerBound + interval}")
  }
)
```

We end up with more smaller partitions (and probably lots of empty ones) but this should let us successfully cut those huge partitions down. This can only be done if you can figure out the distribution of values in the partition though.

Note:: The same thing is possible with union-ing dataframes

Comment: As I *know*, with certainty, the maximum range in each partition, this may be an option.  I could also do a spark DF.groupBy('partitionKey).count.describe, which should give me the distribution.  The partition key is actually a prefix of the first clustering key, which makes this approach even easier.  

I still see this as something of a flaw in spark-cassandra-connector, and it'd be interesting to find a standard way of tackling it.

Comment: Well the issue is without knowing the distribution of c there is no way to know where to establish cutoff points. Untill there are approximate columns stats in Cassandra there isn't much that can be done automatically.. But the point is you do the slice and union before reading the whole thing.